# Is there any MasterPage in windows8 development

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have some pages in the win8 application, most of which have a similar layout, I use `Frame.Navigate` to switch the pages. Just wonder if there is something like `MasterPage` in asp.net webform/mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a page with the layout you want and then use templates to customize it for particular views.  You could have one main view .xaml file and then create a resource dictionary file (for separation purposes) for each different way you use it.

Edit:
I found someone who made a "Master Page" for wpf.  See [here](http://www.software-architects.com/TechnicalArticles/WPFMasterPages/tabid/80/Default.aspx).  You could do something similar for metro.

Comment: Could you please show me a post or an example? I didn't understand how to use templates.

Comment: Templates are pretty basic to xaml.  If you don't know that you should go back and learn the basics.  In the mean time, I found someone who made a "Master Page" for Wpf.  You could do something similar.