# How to create master page for Windows8 app using Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I need to create a Windows8 application but there are multiple elements like progress bar, same app bar and other components that are been used over and over again. In previous application i have been applying these elements in every page. Is there some approach by which I can make a master page and inhert an use it in every page. As we can do in ASP.Net Master page concept?

Comment: duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532155/is-there-any-masterpage-in-windows8-development

Comment: may be you can use an `UserControl`?

Comment: @EasterOfCorpses How can i use UserControl approach? I have seen in a link http://www.software-architects.com/TechnicalArticles/WPFMasterPages/tabid/80/Default.aspx. But there are many System library that are not supported now in WinRT framework. Can you please elaborate on your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with frames :

```
<Page x:Name="MainPage">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Frame x:Name="BasicLayout"/>
    <Frame x:Name="SpecificLayout"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Use `BasicLayout` to show components that are been used over and over again.
Use `SpecificLayout` to show your page-specific content (So you don't directly navigate from the "master" `Frame`, but from the `SpecificLayout` one).

Answer (score 1):

Here is nice tutorial how to create master page for Windows 8 application
[Windows 8 master page tutorial](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2013/windows-8-xaml-tips-master-pages)